# JW Flash Player cannot set file to play

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jwplayer

I'm using the JW Flash Player on my rails 3.1.3 website, but i cannot set the video i want the player to play.

Im trying like this <%= player(:file=>Event.first.video.url) %>

But no luck it tries to find the /others/video.flv

I don't know what i have to do, i followed this configuration: https://github.com/bagwanpankaj/flash_player_helper

I changed the demo_player to the player.

But no luck.

Thanks ppl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
You need to use the flashvars

```
<%= player({:flashvars =>{:file=>Event.first.video.url}}) %>
```

Thanks